# Checking internet connection 

Tags: android, mobile, error-handling, wifi

I check the connection with

```
ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

i have wifi and i get wrong status on my cell phone what could i do ?

Comment: (wifi.isConnected()) gave you false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLease use following standard method to check weather Internet connection is connected or not.....

```
public static final boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
        if (context != null) {
            ConnectivityManager mgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            if (mgr != null) {
                boolean mobileNetwork = false;
                boolean wifiNetwork = false;

                NetworkInfo mobileInfo = mgr
                        .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
                NetworkInfo wifiInfo = mgr
                        .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

                if (mobileInfo != null)
                    mobileNetwork = mobileInfo.isConnected();
                if (wifiInfo != null)
                    wifiNetwork = wifiInfo.isConnected();

                return (mobileNetwork || wifiNetwork);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you given the required permissions mentioned below in the manifest file ...

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```